# What does the SSL error 140612029986456:error:140780E5:SSL mean?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl

I am [trying to debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48617957/how-to-debug-a-wss-application-which-terminates-ssl-and-exposes-the-websocket) the SSL connection of a client I do not have control over.

A possibility I discovered is to use `openssl` as a server to check whether the SSL connection is correctly initiated, and if not - why.

The basic connection ends with

```
root@elk:~# openssl s_server -key sonoff.key -cert sonoff.crt -accept 5555 -www
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT
bad gethostbyaddr
140612029986456:error:140780E5:SSL routines:ssl23_read:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:137:
```

**What does this error actually mean?**

The searches I did point to various bugs, but they all gravitate around "incorrect certificates". The certificates I use are correct, although self-signed. What in the message (or the `-debug` version below) could suggest this? Specifically: could this be an indication of the device checking the certificate and aborting on a self-signed?

```
root@elk:~# openssl s_server -key sonoff.key -cert sonoff.crt -accept 5555 -www -debug
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT

bad gethostbyaddr
read from 0xb2ca20 [0xb32110] (11 bytes => 11 (0xB))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 4f 01 00 00-4b 03 03                  ....O...K..
read from 0xb2ca20 [0xb3211e] (73 bytes => 73 (0x49))
0000 - 1b da e3 8f 9a d2 af 66-81 b5 62 95 7e 44 fc 3b   .......f..b.~D.;
0010 - 75 48 90 da 51 03 f6 ad-33 81 ec 15 16 42 2b f2   uH..Q...3....B+.
0020 - 00 00 12 00 3d 00 35 00-3c 00 2f 00 b7 00 95 00   ....=.5.<./.....
0030 - b6 00 94 00 ff 01 00 00-10 00 0d 00 0c 00 0a 06   ................
0040 - 01 05 01 04 01 03 01 02-01                        .........
write to 0xb2ca20 [0xb3bc00] (86 bytes => 86 (0x56))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 51 02 00 00-4d 03 03 2b ca 7c 43 47   ....Q...M..+.|CG
0010 - 06 ae 7e 1e b3 9c 71 7a-ca 5d 6d 98 54 4e 1c 5a   ..~...qz.]m.TN.Z
0020 - b7 f9 38 2c 0d 3e de e0-62 a6 8a 20 2a 42 cf 9e   ..8,.>..b.. *B..
0030 - ba 1e 8c a3 03 24 e1 34-9e 15 2e d8 90 77 73 74   .....$.4.....wst
0040 - 78 33 e6 45 83 34 ca 11-ae 97 4e 18 00 3d 00 00   x3.E.4....N..=..
0050 - 05 ff 01 00 01                                    .....
0056 - <SPACES/NULS>
write to 0xb2ca20 [0xb3bc00] (1298 bytes => 1298 (0x512))
0000 - 16 03 03 05 0d 0b 00 05-09 00 05 06 00 05 03 30   ...............0
0010 - 82 04 ff 30 82 02 e7 a0-03 02 01 02 02 09 00 df   ...0............
0020 - 41 71 c6 48 ff eb 19 30-0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7   Aq.H...0...*.H..
0030 - 0d 01 01 0b 05 00 30 16-31 14 30 12 06 03 55 04   ......0.1.0...U.
0040 - 03 0c 0b 65 78 61 6d 70-6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d 30 1e   ...example.com0.
0050 - 17 0d 31 38 30 32 30 34-31 38 31 33 35 36 5a 17   ..180204181356Z.
0060 - 0d 32 38 30 32 30 32 31-38 31 33 35 36 5a 30 16   .280202181356Z0.
0070 - 31 14 30 12 06 03 55 04-03 0c 0b 65 78 61 6d 70   1.0...U....examp
0080 - 6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d 30 82-02 22 30 0d 06 09 2a 86   le.com0.."0...*.
0090 - 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01 05-00 03 82 02 0f 00 30 82   H.............0.
00a0 - 02 0a 02 82 02 01 00 e0-22 b0 41 79 e5 60 92 2c   ........".Ay.`.,
00b0 - c7 1c 97 84 f8 16 46 39-27 67 26 ad d7 c8 dc a4   ......F9'g&.....
00c0 - 18 2e 5a 1a aa f7 92 b0-71 8f f8 a5 e0 d9 52 d3   ..Z.....q.....R.
00d0 - 6a c9 e1 ae 7c ce f1 1c-92 99 dd 77 b7 f7 db b3   j...|......w....
00e0 - 2b f4 96 23 d4 d8 08 e8-e2 f2 15 7b 41 16 30 3d   +..#.......{A.0=
00f0 - 21 cd 5f b0 3d 5a 0c ec-60 9b d8 78 99 32 c4 9f   !._.=Z..`..x.2..
0100 - 3c 1b 50 d9 d4 cf f0 4b-58 ca c6 6f 56 f5 57 04   <.P....KX..oV.W.
0110 - c9 d5 60 56 d2 25 66 ee-fe f0 da 79 d6 f2 a5 67   ..`V.%f....y...g
0120 - 08 7a 19 e6 82 90 5c e0-a1 63 cf 4b a8 43 c6 d3   .z....\..c.K.C..
0130 - 08 a0 22 4a df be 42 22-8b c9 6f 81 d1 b0 d8 e0   .."J..B"..o.....
0140 - 24 79 b3 3a ad 10 af bd-7a 43 56 a6 87 ad d2 d4   $y.:....zCV.....
0150 - 96 cf 12 f9 9a 42 7a c7-63 07 f7 cc a9 a5 50 1e   .....Bz.c.....P.
0160 - bf 4d 2d ae e3 74 b7 a7-66 ca ab 44 66 db f5 e2   .M-..t..f..Df...
0170 - 28 dd a8 6f 76 0a 5a d4-8d 42 c6 a0 16 c2 bd d9   (..ov.Z..B......
0180 - 25 38 74 dc bc d3 95 03-b9 13 39 c0 4a cd d9 c9   %8t.......9.J...
0190 - cb 34 bf 9e 48 1e e4 56-8f 47 9c 33 ed eb d6 db   .4..H..V.G.3....
01a0 - 5e b7 46 85 d4 49 48 f3-24 ec 01 c3 98 74 50 f9   ^.F..IH.$....tP.
01b0 - 05 71 01 b5 96 f4 b5 bc-a3 57 78 3f c7 4f 10 1e   .q.......Wx?.O..
01c0 - da 96 59 c0 6d c1 13 64-52 7b f8 d7 88 59 29 ba   ..Y.m..dR{...Y).
01d0 - b7 5a ec a2 a7 1e 86 bb-ea 8b f8 03 e3 73 b3 6e   .Z...........s.n
01e0 - 70 27 29 b6 92 31 4f 52-73 f0 62 91 3e 90 53 40   p')..1ORs.b.>.S@
01f0 - d0 00 e2 1d 80 5e 82 a9-5e fc 56 2f 76 d9 40 39   .....^..^.V/v.@9
0200 - 85 e3 4e 55 d2 a7 47 06-27 92 d9 ec dd 7e 7d c2   ..NU..G.'....~}.
0210 - 07 6d 73 9b 58 75 da ba-cd 65 e3 d9 3b da 78 4e   .ms.Xu...e..;.xN
0220 - 96 81 c1 d1 2f f2 c0 65-e0 a2 12 33 1c eb 0c 2a   ..../..e...3...*
0230 - 10 c6 ea 87 4c 7a a5 d7-c3 4c a8 45 06 8d ca a5   ....Lz...L.E....
0240 - 90 7d e0 57 be e5 17 f0-13 41 28 6e f6 f3 cb b3   .}.W.....A(n....
0250 - d4 9b fa b1 f9 30 a1 b4-2e a4 de 73 39 35 82 32   .....0.....s95.2
0260 - de 55 f9 70 ee ca 8a d2-62 64 fc fb d7 56 17 c7   .U.p....bd...V..
0270 - 9a 3c 4f 3d b1 4a 1d 37-fb ad 40 ef c4 14 cf 08   .<O=.J.7..@.....
0280 - 57 8e 68 5f 2b d4 3b cc-bb 23 9f 83 64 e3 22 39   W.h_+.;..#..d."9
0290 - 53 30 5c 4d 0f d8 4d 2a-5a 23 e6 ee 06 b6 38 5d   S0\M..M*Z#....8]
02a0 - 83 ef 91 f8 25 a6 e3 02-03 01 00 01 a3 50 30 4e   ....%........P0N
02b0 - 30 1d 06 03 55 1d 0e 04-16 04 14 bf 22 b8 2a ec   0...U.......".*.
02c0 - f6 61 a9 05 50 d8 6a f5-35 bd 32 3e 7c 9b d7 30   .a..P.j.5.2>|..0
02d0 - 1f 06 03 55 1d 23 04 18-30 16 80 14 bf 22 b8 2a   ...U.#..0....".*
02e0 - ec f6 61 a9 05 50 d8 6a-f5 35 bd 32 3e 7c 9b d7   ..a..P.j.5.2>|..
02f0 - 30 0c 06 03 55 1d 13 04-05 30 03 01 01 ff 30 0d   0...U....0....0.
0300 - 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d-01 01 0b 05 00 03 82 02   ..*.H...........
0310 - 01 00 35 e5 1e a9 74 4f-78 59 c0 fd da a4 71 7a   ..5...tOxY....qz
0320 - 4e 9d b7 13 42 5b d5 f3-95 1b 48 a6 91 c8 84 be   N...B[....H.....
0330 - fc 67 ed 92 4e 2e f2 e5-6e 14 38 a5 af 51 7f 54   .g..N...n.8..Q.T
0340 - 11 5f ed 15 bd a6 d9 ef-9c ef ee db ed fb 39 45   ._............9E
0350 - e2 5e a9 53 66 73 40 98-27 38 4d a3 1d 5f eb d3   .^.Sfs@.'8M.._..
0360 - f8 33 01 3d ce 08 61 60-e1 ee 91 28 98 0a a2 17   .3.=..a`...(....
0370 - 28 17 39 c1 af 1e d2 f7-42 c6 5f ff a2 fa 77 2a   (.9.....B._...w*
0380 - f0 4b ed 4f ea d4 55 b4-4d 02 63 4f 9f 12 ab 86   .K.O..U.M.cO....
0390 - 26 a6 24 26 7e 26 e2 55-89 6b 7d 52 3c 48 ad 4c   &.$&~&.U.k}R<H.L
03a0 - 0c 76 64 7d a7 8f ff 9e-23 28 4c d5 79 85 ea 0c   .vd}....#(L.y...
03b0 - ee 54 31 24 e2 66 53 4c-ae a6 a6 43 c5 e1 16 c7   .T1$.fSL...C....
03c0 - 48 b3 af 49 c9 f6 30 e6-4a da 2f 9b 1a 9d 5f 15   H..I..0.J./..._.
03d0 - ff ac 9e c7 d3 e4 85 55-1d d6 42 af 58 1e 57 d1   .......U..B.X.W.
03e0 - 84 4f 87 a7 43 10 e8 13-42 fd 49 fa c1 a2 ba 6a   .O..C...B.I....j
03f0 - 30 a4 1e fb db be 99 16-a1 dc 1e 45 45 54 c3 89   0..........EET..
0400 - b8 b6 b8 74 90 2f 8b 8c-68 49 07 a2 7c 0d a6 d6   ...t./..hI..|...
0410 - 3c 80 e2 94 66 b0 83 1f-e3 29 02 4d 76 44 1e 65   <...f....).MvD.e
0420 - 57 7c 9e f2 01 0a 77 cd-c5 85 43 53 9e e7 56 21   W|....w...CS..V!
0430 - 4b 55 05 78 0e 6b 7a 14-44 69 d8 cb 06 de 65 9a   KU.x.kz.Di....e.
0440 - 0a 8b 15 11 4e 21 c6 1d-be d4 6c 45 96 88 f2 04   ....N!....lE....
0450 - d5 ff 03 fd d3 24 7d 25-22 8b 22 37 99 4b 22 fa   .....$}%"."7.K".
0460 - 8f 99 ec 71 88 58 8e 03-9f 76 19 a2 05 a6 3b bc   ...q.X...v....;.
0470 - 87 d8 90 db c1 cc 98 f9-1f c5 00 96 e4 90 3d ad   ..............=.
0480 - d0 fa a1 d5 b6 71 74 7d-0c a3 f2 79 5a e6 31 fb   .....qt}...yZ.1.
0490 - de 65 41 46 39 78 bd d6-c1 b0 1a 44 16 a1 ed 27   .eAF9x.....D...'
04a0 - c6 e7 d6 ab f0 2f 0f 78-a6 78 01 2c ed 18 bb 47   ...../.x.x.,...G
04b0 - 34 54 ee 73 1b 99 83 ca-bf d7 07 65 40 03 f2 75   4T.s.......e@..u
04c0 - 98 d4 f3 22 6c 2f 77 1e-ec e7 1e bf 31 28 90 c4   ..."l/w.....1(..
04d0 - 0c 7a 37 cc 85 37 59 42-94 21 90 05 9e e0 60 51   .z7..7YB.!....`Q
04e0 - 0a 83 b8 29 45 37 06 5a-5e a3 b3 e0 08 cf 48 9b   ...)E7.Z^.....H.
04f0 - 51 17 7b 4c fb 6d 06 e9-4f dd 45 42 42 83 c2 f6   Q.{L.m..O.EBB...
0500 - b3 70 29 86 08 c4 28 f7-b4 d6 1f a1 63 94 f7 75   .p)...(.....c..u
0510 - 8f ba                                             ..
write to 0xb2ca20 [0xb3bc00] (9 bytes => 9 (0x9))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 04 0e                                 ......
0009 - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0xb2ca20 [0xb32113] (5 bytes => 0 (0x0))
140570414024344:error:140780E5:SSL routines:ssl23_read:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:137:
```

EDIT: a `K12` dump of the session:

```
+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:07,529,418   ETHER
|0   |8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|08|00|45|00|00|2c|05|fb|00|00|7f|06|16|28|0a|64|0a|71|0a|c8|00|0d|58|a7|15|b3|00|36|bf|c5|00|00|00|00|60|02|16|d0|33|57|00|00|02|04|05|b4|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:07,529,450   ETHER
|0   |1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|08|00|45|00|00|2c|00|00|40|00|40|06|1b|23|0a|c8|00|0d|0a|64|0a|71|15|b3|58|a7|62|61|d4|6d|00|36|bf|c6|60|12|72|10|1f|c8|00|00|02|04|05|b4|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:07,668,343   ETHER
|0   |8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|08|00|45|00|00|7c|05|fc|00|00|7f|06|15|d7|0a|64|0a|71|0a|c8|00|0d|58|a7|15|b3|00|36|bf|c6|62|61|d4|6e|50|18|16|d0|67|d0|00|00|16|03|01|00|4f|01|00|00|4b|03|03|6e|30|37|19|a3|c0|a4|d5|d1|3c|8b|ed|76|72|e2|9f|d5|5e|57|3e|9e|98|b7|33|a9|12|54|de|40|32|df|34|00|00|12|00|3d|00|35|00|3c|00|2f|00|b7|00|95|00|b6|00|94|00|ff|01|00|00|10|00|0d|00|0c|00|0a|06|01|05|01|04|01|03|01|02|01|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:07,668,359   ETHER
|0   |1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|08|00|45|00|00|28|39|19|40|00|40|06|e2|0d|0a|c8|00|0d|0a|64|0a|71|15|b3|58|a7|62|61|d4|6e|00|36|c0|1a|50|10|72|10|1f|c4|00|00|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:07,668,617   ETHER
|0   |1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|08|00|45|00|05|99|39|1a|40|00|40|06|dc|9b|0a|c8|00|0d|0a|64|0a|71|15|b3|58|a7|62|61|d4|6e|00|36|c0|1a|50|18|72|10|25|35|00|00|16|03|01|00|51|02|00|00|4d|03|01|e9|4e|66|d1|56|43|c2|f8|df|95|62|d2|a1|8f|99|85|39|d3|22|4e|92|64|85|75|47|8f|29|f5|15|11|8e|10|20|b7|07|bc|84|e7|15|1e|6b|53|ed|6c|d5|1c|f6|15|10|ab|03|94|db|15|19|47|b7|43|04|30|59|fb|f2|52|e5|00|35|00|00|05|ff|01|00|01|00|16|03|01|05|0d|0b|00|05|09|00|05|06|00|05|03|30|82|04|ff|30|82|02|e7|a0|03|02|01|02|02|09|00|df|41|71|c6|48|ff|eb|19|30|0d|06|09|2a|86|48|86|f7|0d|01|01|0b|05|00|30|16|31|14|30|12|06|03|55|04|03|0c|0b|65|78|61|6d|70|6c|65|2e|63|6f|6d|30|1e|17|0d|31|38|30|32|30|34|31|38|31|33|35|36|5a|17|0d|32|38|30|32|30|32|31|38|31|33|35|36|5a|30|16|31|14|30|12|06|03|55|04|03|0c|0b|65|78|61|6d|70|6c|65|2e|63|6f|6d|30|82|02|22|30|0d|06|09|2a|86|48|86|f7|0d|01|01|01|05|00|03|82|02|0f|00|30|82|02|0a|02|82|02|01|00|e0|22|b0|41|79|e5|60|92|2c|c7|1c|97|84|f8|16|46|39|27|67|26|ad|d7|c8|dc|a4|18|2e|5a|1a|aa|f7|92|b0|71|8f|f8|a5|e0|d9|52|d3|6a|c9|e1|ae|7c|ce|f1|1c|92|99|dd|77|b7|f7|db|b3|2b|f4|96|23|d4|d8|08|e8|e2|f2|15|7b|41|16|30|3d|21|cd|5f|b0|3d|5a|0c|ec|60|9b|d8|78|99|32|c4|9f|3c|1b|50|d9|d4|cf|f0|4b|58|ca|c6|6f|56|f5|57|04|c9|d5|60|56|d2|25|66|ee|fe|f0|da|79|d6|f2|a5|67|08|7a|19|e6|82|90|5c|e0|a1|63|cf|4b|a8|43|c6|d3|08|a0|22|4a|df|be|42|22|8b|c9|6f|81|d1|b0|d8|e0|24|79|b3|3a|ad|10|af|bd|7a|43|56|a6|87|ad|d2|d4|96|cf|12|f9|9a|42|7a|c7|63|07|f7|cc|a9|a5|50|1e|bf|4d|2d|ae|e3|74|b7|a7|66|ca|ab|44|66|db|f5|e2|28|dd|a8|6f|76|0a|5a|d4|8d|42|c6|a0|16|c2|bd|d9|25|38|74|dc|bc|d3|95|03|b9|13|39|c0|4a|cd|d9|c9|cb|34|bf|9e|48|1e|e4|56|8f|47|9c|33|ed|eb|d6|db|5e|b7|46|85|d4|49|48|f3|24|ec|01|c3|98|74|50|f9|05|71|01|b5|96|f4|b5|bc|a3|57|78|3f|c7|4f|10|1e|da|96|59|c0|6d|c1|13|64|52|7b|f8|d7|88|59|29|ba|b7|5a|ec|a2|a7|1e|86|bb|ea|8b|f8|03|e3|73|b3|6e|70|27|29|b6|92|31|4f|52|73|f0|62|91|3e|90|53|40|d0|00|e2|1d|80|5e|82|a9|5e|fc|56|2f|76|d9|40|39|85|e3|4e|55|d2|a7|47|06|27|92|d9|ec|dd|7e|7d|c2|07|6d|73|9b|58|75|da|ba|cd|65|e3|d9|3b|da|78|4e|96|81|c1|d1|2f|f2|c0|65|e0|a2|12|33|1c|eb|0c|2a|10|c6|ea|87|4c|7a|a5|d7|c3|4c|a8|45|06|8d|ca|a5|90|7d|e0|57|be|e5|17|f0|13|41|28|6e|f6|f3|cb|b3|d4|9b|fa|b1|f9|30|a1|b4|2e|a4|de|73|39|35|82|32|de|55|f9|70|ee|ca|8a|d2|62|64|fc|fb|d7|56|17|c7|9a|3c|4f|3d|b1|4a|1d|37|fb|ad|40|ef|c4|14|cf|08|57|8e|68|5f|2b|d4|3b|cc|bb|23|9f|83|64|e3|22|39|53|30|5c|4d|0f|d8|4d|2a|5a|23|e6|ee|06|b6|38|5d|83|ef|91|f8|25|a6|e3|02|03|01|00|01|a3|50|30|4e|30|1d|06|03|55|1d|0e|04|16|04|14|bf|22|b8|2a|ec|f6|61|a9|05|50|d8|6a|f5|35|bd|32|3e|7c|9b|d7|30|1f|06|03|55|1d|23|04|18|30|16|80|14|bf|22|b8|2a|ec|f6|61|a9|05|50|d8|6a|f5|35|bd|32|3e|7c|9b|d7|30|0c|06|03|55|1d|13|04|05|30|03|01|01|ff|30|0d|06|09|2a|86|48|86|f7|0d|01|01|0b|05|00|03|82|02|01|00|35|e5|1e|a9|74|4f|78|59|c0|fd|da|a4|71|7a|4e|9d|b7|13|42|5b|d5|f3|95|1b|48|a6|91|c8|84|be|fc|67|ed|92|4e|2e|f2|e5|6e|14|38|a5|af|51|7f|54|11|5f|ed|15|bd|a6|d9|ef|9c|ef|ee|db|ed|fb|39|45|e2|5e|a9|53|66|73|40|98|27|38|4d|a3|1d|5f|eb|d3|f8|33|01|3d|ce|08|61|60|e1|ee|91|28|98|0a|a2|17|28|17|39|c1|af|1e|d2|f7|42|c6|5f|ff|a2|fa|77|2a|f0|4b|ed|4f|ea|d4|55|b4|4d|02|63|4f|9f|12|ab|86|26|a6|24|26|7e|26|e2|55|89|6b|7d|52|3c|48|ad|4c|0c|76|64|7d|a7|8f|ff|9e|23|28|4c|d5|79|85|ea|0c|ee|54|31|24|e2|66|53|4c|ae|a6|a6|43|c5|e1|16|c7|48|b3|af|49|c9|f6|30|e6|4a|da|2f|9b|1a|9d|5f|15|ff|ac|9e|c7|d3|e4|85|55|1d|d6|42|af|58|1e|57|d1|84|4f|87|a7|43|10|e8|13|42|fd|49|fa|c1|a2|ba|6a|30|a4|1e|fb|db|be|99|16|a1|dc|1e|45|45|54|c3|89|b8|b6|b8|74|90|2f|8b|8c|68|49|07|a2|7c|0d|a6|d6|3c|80|e2|94|66|b0|83|1f|e3|29|02|4d|76|44|1e|65|57|7c|9e|f2|01|0a|77|cd|c5|85|43|53|9e|e7|56|21|4b|55|05|78|0e|6b|7a|14|44|69|d8|cb|06|de|65|9a|0a|8b|15|11|4e|21|c6|1d|be|d4|6c|45|96|88|f2|04|d5|ff|03|fd|d3|24|7d|25|22|8b|22|37|99|4b|22|fa|8f|99|ec|71|88|58|8e|03|9f|76|19|a2|05|a6|3b|bc|87|d8|90|db|c1|cc|98|f9|1f|c5|00|96|e4|90|3d|ad|d0|fa|a1|d5|b6|71|74|7d|0c|a3|f2|79|5a|e6|31|fb|de|65|41|46|39|78|bd|d6|c1|b0|1a|44|16|a1|ed|27|c6|e7|d6|ab|f0|2f|0f|78|a6|78|01|2c|ed|18|bb|47|34|54|ee|73|1b|99|83|ca|bf|d7|07|65|40|03|f2|75|98|d4|f3|22|6c|2f|77|1e|ec|e7|1e|bf|31|28|90|c4|0c|7a|37|cc|85|37|59|42|94|21|90|05|9e|e0|60|51|0a|83|b8|29|45|37|06|5a|5e|a3|b3|e0|08|cf|48|9b|51|17|7b|4c|fb|6d|06|e9|4f|dd|45|42|42|83|c2|f6|b3|70|29|86|08|c4|28|f7|b4|d6|1f|a1|63|94|f7|75|8f|ba|16|03|01|00|04|0e|00|00|00|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:08,150,907   ETHER
|0   |1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|08|00|45|00|05|99|39|1b|40|00|40|06|dc|9a|0a|c8|00|0d|0a|64|0a|71|15|b3|58|a7|62|61|d4|6e|00|36|c0|1a|50|18|72|10|25|35|00|00|16|03|01|00|51|02|00|00|4d|03|01|e9|4e|66|d1|56|43|c2|f8|df|95|62|d2|a1|8f|99|85|39|d3|22|4e|92|64|85|75|47|8f|29|f5|15|11|8e|10|20|b7|07|bc|84|e7|15|1e|6b|53|ed|6c|d5|1c|f6|15|10|ab|03|94|db|15|19|47|b7|43|04|30|59|fb|f2|52|e5|00|35|00|00|05|ff|01|00|01|00|16|03|01|05|0d|0b|00|05|09|00|05|06|00|05|03|30|82|04|ff|30|82|02|e7|a0|03|02|01|02|02|09|00|df|41|71|c6|48|ff|eb|19|30|0d|06|09|2a|86|48|86|f7|0d|01|01|0b|05|00|30|16|31|14|30|12|06|03|55|04|03|0c|0b|65|78|61|6d|70|6c|65|2e|63|6f|6d|30|1e|17|0d|31|38|30|32|30|34|31|38|31|33|35|36|5a|17|0d|32|38|30|32|30|32|31|38|31|33|35|36|5a|30|16|31|14|30|12|06|03|55|04|03|0c|0b|65|78|61|6d|70|6c|65|2e|63|6f|6d|30|82|02|22|30|0d|06|09|2a|86|48|86|f7|0d|01|01|01|05|00|03|82|02|0f|00|30|82|02|0a|02|82|02|01|00|e0|22|b0|41|79|e5|60|92|2c|c7|1c|97|84|f8|16|46|39|27|67|26|ad|d7|c8|dc|a4|18|2e|5a|1a|aa|f7|92|b0|71|8f|f8|a5|e0|d9|52|d3|6a|c9|e1|ae|7c|ce|f1|1c|92|99|dd|77|b7|f7|db|b3|2b|f4|96|23|d4|d8|08|e8|e2|f2|15|7b|41|16|30|3d|21|cd|5f|b0|3d|5a|0c|ec|60|9b|d8|78|99|32|c4|9f|3c|1b|50|d9|d4|cf|f0|4b|58|ca|c6|6f|56|f5|57|04|c9|d5|60|56|d2|25|66|ee|fe|f0|da|79|d6|f2|a5|67|08|7a|19|e6|82|90|5c|e0|a1|63|cf|4b|a8|43|c6|d3|08|a0|22|4a|df|be|42|22|8b|c9|6f|81|d1|b0|d8|e0|24|79|b3|3a|ad|10|af|bd|7a|43|56|a6|87|ad|d2|d4|96|cf|12|f9|9a|42|7a|c7|63|07|f7|cc|a9|a5|50|1e|bf|4d|2d|ae|e3|74|b7|a7|66|ca|ab|44|66|db|f5|e2|28|dd|a8|6f|76|0a|5a|d4|8d|42|c6|a0|16|c2|bd|d9|25|38|74|dc|bc|d3|95|03|b9|13|39|c0|4a|cd|d9|c9|cb|34|bf|9e|48|1e|e4|56|8f|47|9c|33|ed|eb|d6|db|5e|b7|46|85|d4|49|48|f3|24|ec|01|c3|98|74|50|f9|05|71|01|b5|96|f4|b5|bc|a3|57|78|3f|c7|4f|10|1e|da|96|59|c0|6d|c1|13|64|52|7b|f8|d7|88|59|29|ba|b7|5a|ec|a2|a7|1e|86|bb|ea|8b|f8|03|e3|73|b3|6e|70|27|29|b6|92|31|4f|52|73|f0|62|91|3e|90|53|40|d0|00|e2|1d|80|5e|82|a9|5e|fc|56|2f|76|d9|40|39|85|e3|4e|55|d2|a7|47|06|27|92|d9|ec|dd|7e|7d|c2|07|6d|73|9b|58|75|da|ba|cd|65|e3|d9|3b|da|78|4e|96|81|c1|d1|2f|f2|c0|65|e0|a2|12|33|1c|eb|0c|2a|10|c6|ea|87|4c|7a|a5|d7|c3|4c|a8|45|06|8d|ca|a5|90|7d|e0|57|be|e5|17|f0|13|41|28|6e|f6|f3|cb|b3|d4|9b|fa|b1|f9|30|a1|b4|2e|a4|de|73|39|35|82|32|de|55|f9|70|ee|ca|8a|d2|62|64|fc|fb|d7|56|17|c7|9a|3c|4f|3d|b1|4a|1d|37|fb|ad|40|ef|c4|14|cf|08|57|8e|68|5f|2b|d4|3b|cc|bb|23|9f|83|64|e3|22|39|53|30|5c|4d|0f|d8|4d|2a|5a|23|e6|ee|06|b6|38|5d|83|ef|91|f8|25|a6|e3|02|03|01|00|01|a3|50|30|4e|30|1d|06|03|55|1d|0e|04|16|04|14|bf|22|b8|2a|ec|f6|61|a9|05|50|d8|6a|f5|35|bd|32|3e|7c|9b|d7|30|1f|06|03|55|1d|23|04|18|30|16|80|14|bf|22|b8|2a|ec|f6|61|a9|05|50|d8|6a|f5|35|bd|32|3e|7c|9b|d7|30|0c|06|03|55|1d|13|04|05|30|03|01|01|ff|30|0d|06|09|2a|86|48|86|f7|0d|01|01|0b|05|00|03|82|02|01|00|35|e5|1e|a9|74|4f|78|59|c0|fd|da|a4|71|7a|4e|9d|b7|13|42|5b|d5|f3|95|1b|48|a6|91|c8|84|be|fc|67|ed|92|4e|2e|f2|e5|6e|14|38|a5|af|51|7f|54|11|5f|ed|15|bd|a6|d9|ef|9c|ef|ee|db|ed|fb|39|45|e2|5e|a9|53|66|73|40|98|27|38|4d|a3|1d|5f|eb|d3|f8|33|01|3d|ce|08|61|60|e1|ee|91|28|98|0a|a2|17|28|17|39|c1|af|1e|d2|f7|42|c6|5f|ff|a2|fa|77|2a|f0|4b|ed|4f|ea|d4|55|b4|4d|02|63|4f|9f|12|ab|86|26|a6|24|26|7e|26|e2|55|89|6b|7d|52|3c|48|ad|4c|0c|76|64|7d|a7|8f|ff|9e|23|28|4c|d5|79|85|ea|0c|ee|54|31|24|e2|66|53|4c|ae|a6|a6|43|c5|e1|16|c7|48|b3|af|49|c9|f6|30|e6|4a|da|2f|9b|1a|9d|5f|15|ff|ac|9e|c7|d3|e4|85|55|1d|d6|42|af|58|1e|57|d1|84|4f|87|a7|43|10|e8|13|42|fd|49|fa|c1|a2|ba|6a|30|a4|1e|fb|db|be|99|16|a1|dc|1e|45|45|54|c3|89|b8|b6|b8|74|90|2f|8b|8c|68|49|07|a2|7c|0d|a6|d6|3c|80|e2|94|66|b0|83|1f|e3|29|02|4d|76|44|1e|65|57|7c|9e|f2|01|0a|77|cd|c5|85|43|53|9e|e7|56|21|4b|55|05|78|0e|6b|7a|14|44|69|d8|cb|06|de|65|9a|0a|8b|15|11|4e|21|c6|1d|be|d4|6c|45|96|88|f2|04|d5|ff|03|fd|d3|24|7d|25|22|8b|22|37|99|4b|22|fa|8f|99|ec|71|88|58|8e|03|9f|76|19|a2|05|a6|3b|bc|87|d8|90|db|c1|cc|98|f9|1f|c5|00|96|e4|90|3d|ad|d0|fa|a1|d5|b6|71|74|7d|0c|a3|f2|79|5a|e6|31|fb|de|65|41|46|39|78|bd|d6|c1|b0|1a|44|16|a1|ed|27|c6|e7|d6|ab|f0|2f|0f|78|a6|78|01|2c|ed|18|bb|47|34|54|ee|73|1b|99|83|ca|bf|d7|07|65|40|03|f2|75|98|d4|f3|22|6c|2f|77|1e|ec|e7|1e|bf|31|28|90|c4|0c|7a|37|cc|85|37|59|42|94|21|90|05|9e|e0|60|51|0a|83|b8|29|45|37|06|5a|5e|a3|b3|e0|08|cf|48|9b|51|17|7b|4c|fb|6d|06|e9|4f|dd|45|42|42|83|c2|f6|b3|70|29|86|08|c4|28|f7|b4|d6|1f|a1|63|94|f7|75|8f|ba|16|03|01|00|04|0e|00|00|00|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:08,556,603   ETHER
|0   |8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|08|00|45|00|00|7c|05|fd|00|00|7f|06|15|d6|0a|64|0a|71|0a|c8|00|0d|58|a7|15|b3|00|36|bf|c6|62|61|d4|6e|50|18|16|d0|67|d0|00|00|16|03|01|00|4f|01|00|00|4b|03|03|6e|30|37|19|a3|c0|a4|d5|d1|3c|8b|ed|76|72|e2|9f|d5|5e|57|3e|9e|98|b7|33|a9|12|54|de|40|32|df|34|00|00|12|00|3d|00|35|00|3c|00|2f|00|b7|00|95|00|b6|00|94|00|ff|01|00|00|10|00|0d|00|0c|00|0a|06|01|05|01|04|01|03|01|02|01|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:08,556,617   ETHER
|0   |1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|08|00|45|00|00|28|39|1c|40|00|40|06|e2|0a|0a|c8|00|0d|0a|64|0a|71|15|b3|58|a7|62|61|d9|df|00|36|c0|1a|50|10|72|10|1f|c4|00|00|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:08,683,863   ETHER
|0   |8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|08|00|45|00|00|28|05|fe|00|00|7f|06|16|29|0a|64|0a|71|0a|c8|00|0d|58|a7|15|b3|00|36|c0|1a|62|61|d9|df|50|11|11|5f|13|df|00|00|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:08,683,932   ETHER
|0   |1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|08|00|45|00|00|28|39|1d|40|00|40|06|e2|09|0a|c8|00|0d|0a|64|0a|71|15|b3|58|a7|62|61|d9|df|00|36|c0|1b|50|11|72|10|1f|c4|00|00|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:08,762,143   ETHER
|0   |8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|08|00|45|00|00|28|05|ff|00|00|7f|06|16|28|0a|64|0a|71|0a|c8|00|0d|58|a7|15|b3|00|36|c0|1b|62|61|d9|e0|50|10|11|5e|13|df|00|00|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:16,784,169   ETHER
|0   |8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|08|00|45|00|00|2c|06|00|00|00|7f|06|16|23|0a|64|0a|71|0a|c8|00|0d|18|30|15|b3|00|36|e7|9f|00|00|00|00|60|02|16|d0|4b|f4|00|00|02|04|05|b4|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:16,784,184   ETHER
|0   |1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|08|00|45|00|00|2c|00|00|40|00|40|06|1b|23|0a|c8|00|0d|0a|64|0a|71|15|b3|18|30|98|bc|9a|61|00|36|e7|a0|60|12|72|10|1f|c8|00|00|02|04|05|b4|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:16,886,424   ETHER
|0   |8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|08|00|45|00|00|7c|06|01|00|00|7f|06|15|d2|0a|64|0a|71|0a|c8|00|0d|18|30|15|b3|00|36|e7|a0|98|bc|9a|62|50|18|16|d0|70|29|00|00|16|03|01|00|4f|01|00|00|4b|03|03|e5|7a|5a|74|be|6f|f0|54|cf|60|fd|45|d1|15|6e|25|28|82|23|11|ce|26|76|8f|3a|9b|db|bf|31|93|66|24|00|00|12|00|3d|00|35|00|3c|00|2f|00|b7|00|95|00|b6|00|94|00|ff|01|00|00|10|00|0d|00|0c|00|0a|06|01|05|01|04|01|03|01|02|01|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:16,886,440   ETHER
|0   |1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|08|00|45|00|00|28|6c|15|40|00|40|06|af|11|0a|c8|00|0d|0a|64|0a|71|15|b3|18|30|98|bc|9a|62|00|36|e7|f4|50|10|72|10|1f|c4|00|00|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:16,886,658   ETHER
|0   |1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|08|00|45|00|05|99|6c|16|40|00|40|06|a9|9f|0a|c8|00|0d|0a|64|0a|71|15|b3|18|30|98|bc|9a|62|00|36|e7|f4|50|18|72|10|25|35|00|00|16|03|01|00|51|02|00|00|4d|03|01|24|c5|4f|88|a2|2e|d6|95|40|f4|42|c1|97|78|b8|4a|33|43|32|94|d8|81|88|7f|09|44|df|3a|6c|79|d2|3a|20|1d|a7|32|d9|88|67|21|c6|69|f6|70|a7|20|28|0c|ac|a4|da|d0|95|3f|02|4f|51|68|78|7e|bf|1c|53|46|69|00|35|00|00|05|ff|01|00|01|00|16|03|01|05|0d|0b|00|05|09|00|05|06|00|05|03|30|82|04|ff|30|82|02|e7|a0|03|02|01|02|02|09|00|df|41|71|c6|48|ff|eb|19|30|0d|06|09|2a|86|48|86|f7|0d|01|01|0b|05|00|30|16|31|14|30|12|06|03|55|04|03|0c|0b|65|78|61|6d|70|6c|65|2e|63|6f|6d|30|1e|17|0d|31|38|30|32|30|34|31|38|31|33|35|36|5a|17|0d|32|38|30|32|30|32|31|38|31|33|35|36|5a|30|16|31|14|30|12|06|03|55|04|03|0c|0b|65|78|61|6d|70|6c|65|2e|63|6f|6d|30|82|02|22|30|0d|06|09|2a|86|48|86|f7|0d|01|01|01|05|00|03|82|02|0f|00|30|82|02|0a|02|82|02|01|00|e0|22|b0|41|79|e5|60|92|2c|c7|1c|97|84|f8|16|46|39|27|67|26|ad|d7|c8|dc|a4|18|2e|5a|1a|aa|f7|92|b0|71|8f|f8|a5|e0|d9|52|d3|6a|c9|e1|ae|7c|ce|f1|1c|92|99|dd|77|b7|f7|db|b3|2b|f4|96|23|d4|d8|08|e8|e2|f2|15|7b|41|16|30|3d|21|cd|5f|b0|3d|5a|0c|ec|60|9b|d8|78|99|32|c4|9f|3c|1b|50|d9|d4|cf|f0|4b|58|ca|c6|6f|56|f5|57|04|c9|d5|60|56|d2|25|66|ee|fe|f0|da|79|d6|f2|a5|67|08|7a|19|e6|82|90|5c|e0|a1|63|cf|4b|a8|43|c6|d3|08|a0|22|4a|df|be|42|22|8b|c9|6f|81|d1|b0|d8|e0|24|79|b3|3a|ad|10|af|bd|7a|43|56|a6|87|ad|d2|d4|96|cf|12|f9|9a|42|7a|c7|63|07|f7|cc|a9|a5|50|1e|bf|4d|2d|ae|e3|74|b7|a7|66|ca|ab|44|66|db|f5|e2|28|dd|a8|6f|76|0a|5a|d4|8d|42|c6|a0|16|c2|bd|d9|25|38|74|dc|bc|d3|95|03|b9|13|39|c0|4a|cd|d9|c9|cb|34|bf|9e|48|1e|e4|56|8f|47|9c|33|ed|eb|d6|db|5e|b7|46|85|d4|49|48|f3|24|ec|01|c3|98|74|50|f9|05|71|01|b5|96|f4|b5|bc|a3|57|78|3f|c7|4f|10|1e|da|96|59|c0|6d|c1|13|64|52|7b|f8|d7|88|59|29|ba|b7|5a|ec|a2|a7|1e|86|bb|ea|8b|f8|03|e3|73|b3|6e|70|27|29|b6|92|31|4f|52|73|f0|62|91|3e|90|53|40|d0|00|e2|1d|80|5e|82|a9|5e|fc|56|2f|76|d9|40|39|85|e3|4e|55|d2|a7|47|06|27|92|d9|ec|dd|7e|7d|c2|07|6d|73|9b|58|75|da|ba|cd|65|e3|d9|3b|da|78|4e|96|81|c1|d1|2f|f2|c0|65|e0|a2|12|33|1c|eb|0c|2a|10|c6|ea|87|4c|7a|a5|d7|c3|4c|a8|45|06|8d|ca|a5|90|7d|e0|57|be|e5|17|f0|13|41|28|6e|f6|f3|cb|b3|d4|9b|fa|b1|f9|30|a1|b4|2e|a4|de|73|39|35|82|32|de|55|f9|70|ee|ca|8a|d2|62|64|fc|fb|d7|56|17|c7|9a|3c|4f|3d|b1|4a|1d|37|fb|ad|40|ef|c4|14|cf|08|57|8e|68|5f|2b|d4|3b|cc|bb|23|9f|83|64|e3|22|39|53|30|5c|4d|0f|d8|4d|2a|5a|23|e6|ee|06|b6|38|5d|83|ef|91|f8|25|a6|e3|02|03|01|00|01|a3|50|30|4e|30|1d|06|03|55|1d|0e|04|16|04|14|bf|22|b8|2a|ec|f6|61|a9|05|50|d8|6a|f5|35|bd|32|3e|7c|9b|d7|30|1f|06|03|55|1d|23|04|18|30|16|80|14|bf|22|b8|2a|ec|f6|61|a9|05|50|d8|6a|f5|35|bd|32|3e|7c|9b|d7|30|0c|06|03|55|1d|13|04|05|30|03|01|01|ff|30|0d|06|09|2a|86|48|86|f7|0d|01|01|0b|05|00|03|82|02|01|00|35|e5|1e|a9|74|4f|78|59|c0|fd|da|a4|71|7a|4e|9d|b7|13|42|5b|d5|f3|95|1b|48|a6|91|c8|84|be|fc|67|ed|92|4e|2e|f2|e5|6e|14|38|a5|af|51|7f|54|11|5f|ed|15|bd|a6|d9|ef|9c|ef|ee|db|ed|fb|39|45|e2|5e|a9|53|66|73|40|98|27|38|4d|a3|1d|5f|eb|d3|f8|33|01|3d|ce|08|61|60|e1|ee|91|28|98|0a|a2|17|28|17|39|c1|af|1e|d2|f7|42|c6|5f|ff|a2|fa|77|2a|f0|4b|ed|4f|ea|d4|55|b4|4d|02|63|4f|9f|12|ab|86|26|a6|24|26|7e|26|e2|55|89|6b|7d|52|3c|48|ad|4c|0c|76|64|7d|a7|8f|ff|9e|23|28|4c|d5|79|85|ea|0c|ee|54|31|24|e2|66|53|4c|ae|a6|a6|43|c5|e1|16|c7|48|b3|af|49|c9|f6|30|e6|4a|da|2f|9b|1a|9d|5f|15|ff|ac|9e|c7|d3|e4|85|55|1d|d6|42|af|58|1e|57|d1|84|4f|87|a7|43|10|e8|13|42|fd|49|fa|c1|a2|ba|6a|30|a4|1e|fb|db|be|99|16|a1|dc|1e|45|45|54|c3|89|b8|b6|b8|74|90|2f|8b|8c|68|49|07|a2|7c|0d|a6|d6|3c|80|e2|94|66|b0|83|1f|e3|29|02|4d|76|44|1e|65|57|7c|9e|f2|01|0a|77|cd|c5|85|43|53|9e|e7|56|21|4b|55|05|78|0e|6b|7a|14|44|69|d8|cb|06|de|65|9a|0a|8b|15|11|4e|21|c6|1d|be|d4|6c|45|96|88|f2|04|d5|ff|03|fd|d3|24|7d|25|22|8b|22|37|99|4b|22|fa|8f|99|ec|71|88|58|8e|03|9f|76|19|a2|05|a6|3b|bc|87|d8|90|db|c1|cc|98|f9|1f|c5|00|96|e4|90|3d|ad|d0|fa|a1|d5|b6|71|74|7d|0c|a3|f2|79|5a|e6|31|fb|de|65|41|46|39|78|bd|d6|c1|b0|1a|44|16|a1|ed|27|c6|e7|d6|ab|f0|2f|0f|78|a6|78|01|2c|ed|18|bb|47|34|54|ee|73|1b|99|83|ca|bf|d7|07|65|40|03|f2|75|98|d4|f3|22|6c|2f|77|1e|ec|e7|1e|bf|31|28|90|c4|0c|7a|37|cc|85|37|59|42|94|21|90|05|9e|e0|60|51|0a|83|b8|29|45|37|06|5a|5e|a3|b3|e0|08|cf|48|9b|51|17|7b|4c|fb|6d|06|e9|4f|dd|45|42|42|83|c2|f6|b3|70|29|86|08|c4|28|f7|b4|d6|1f|a1|63|94|f7|75|8f|ba|16|03|01|00|04|0e|00|00|00|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:16,933,784   ETHER
|0   |8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|08|00|45|00|00|28|06|02|00|00|7f|06|16|25|0a|64|0a|71|0a|c8|00|0d|18|30|15|b3|00|36|e7|f4|98|bc|9f|d3|50|11|11|5f|30|2d|00|00|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:16,933,874   ETHER
|0   |1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|08|00|45|00|00|28|6c|17|40|00|40|06|af|0f|0a|c8|00|0d|0a|64|0a|71|15|b3|18|30|98|bc|9f|d3|00|36|e7|f5|50|11|72|10|1f|c4|00|00|

+---------+---------------+----------+
18:19:16,973,340   ETHER
|0   |8a|4b|47|20|ce|e4|1e|33|c8|aa|1b|40|08|00|45|00|00|28|06|03|00|00|7f|06|16|24|0a|64|0a|71|0a|c8|00|0d|18|30|15|b3|00|36|e7|f5|98|bc|9f|d4|50|10|11|5e|30|2d|00|00|
```

Comment: `openssl errstr 140780E5` returns *`ssl handshake failure`*. Next, you should probably get a pcap or Wireshark trace. They are usually better than the debug dumps because the trace is dissected for you (instead of raw bytes).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww: there is trace dump in my question (a K12 format so that it can be directly added to the question and not linked to). Also, while not strictly a code problem, it is to debug a Python server (per the first link in the question). Unfortunately as I see it is really in between: not code, but protocol.

Answer (score 2):

> What does this error actually mean?

At the risk of stating the obvious it literally means "the handshake failed" and doesn't give you any more information than that. It could be caused by any number of possible issues. From your debug output we can see that:

1. The client issues a ClientHello to the server
2. The server responds with a ServerHello, a Certificate and a ServerHelloDone.
3. The server then attempts to read a response from the client but this read fails (most probably because the client has aborted - but without sending any kind of alert to indicate the cause of the problem).

Clearly something in the response that your server has sent back to the client has caused the client to just give up. The most likely culprit is the certificate, but its also possible that there is something about the ServerHello it doesn't like (e.g. the server didn't understand some extension that the client sent in its ClientHello, which it refuses to work without...although this is quite unlikely)

Comment: Thanks. This mostly confirms my initial fear that the client is checking the certificate and aborts on a wrong one (I do not know if a client has the ability in the protocol to answer back to the server that the certificate is not correct, ideally with an information why). Since another client (one I control, namely the one from my previous question linked at the beginning) behaves correctly then I think it is game over and I will not  be able to connect to the server (I cannot have a public-CA certificate on a private network)

Comment: TLS 1.2 ideally answers your question ( https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.2.2 ) but you didn't provide any capture. Anyway you accepted an answer saying the faulty part is the server, which we can't prove yet.

Comment: @EugèneAdell: you are right. I added the dump and will wait before acceptiong - I had low hoped in the debugging looking at the end of the TLS exchange

Answer (score 1):

When looking in details to your debug log, it looks like a normal client/server handshake, in TLS 1.2. The last 9 bytes written mean the SERVER HELLO DONE is accomplished, and then the client (the last "read from") is sending 5 bytes that unfortunately we don't have. 5 bytes is a normal thing at this moment, these bytes are supposed to continue with the TLS exchange (Client key exchange,..) and they contain the "hello" byte, the protocol version (2 bytes), and the data length (2 bytes).
All this work would be easier for me if you provided a network capture. But OK, we have some information.

There is one reason to make openssl bug at this moment, when we receive 5 bytes instead of 11. This code will later generate the same handshake failure that you get :

```
 * Request this many bytes in initial read.
 * We can detect SSL 3.0/TLS 1.0 Client Hellos
 * ('type == 3') correctly only when the following
 * is in a single record, which is not guaranteed by
 * the protocol specification:
 * Byte  Content
 *  0     type            \
 *  1/2   version          > record header
 *  3/4   length          /
 *  5     msg_type        \
 *  6-8   length           > Client Hello message
 *  9/10  client_version  /
 */
char buf_space[11];
```

But without any capture, it's almost impossible to say whether the client is sending a wrong Client key exchange, or if it's your openssl version which is faulty (more likely, it's the client).
Can you check what openssl version you are running ?

Comment: Thanks, I added a `K12` text dump of the session (importable into Wireshark) to the question. The `openssl` version is `OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips`

Comment: this capture shows TLS 1.0 traffic, not TLS1.2. Did you change anything ? We see that the client decides to stop communicating (Matt's hypothesis)

Comment: I ran the exact same command, with `tcpdump` in another window. The device is plugged in all the  time and continuously attempts to connect to the server.

Comment: is it your s_server which is running as the server, or your real application ? it could explain why we see different server protocols.

Comment: `read (5 => 0)` means OpenSSL _tried_ to read the record header (which is 5 bytes) but actually got 0 bytes -- apparently our system's TCP/IP stack closed the connection and thinks it was acked but it's not clear if it really is, see my answer.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for helping. As I asked to the question owner, we need to know if the capture was made with the real server answer, or s_server, because it doesn't match the TLS version (and we don't see those 5 bytes too).

Comment: @EugèneAdell: it was done with `s_server`, ran as in the question. My real server is off for the moment.

Comment: Your K12 shows TLS 1.0 for both client and server (Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)), while the openssl debug shows TLS 1.2 for the server (0000 - 16 03 03). How is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

**This appears to be a network or stack problem.**

Assuming we are the server at 10.200.0.13 and the client is 10.100.10.113 your network dump decodes as follows:

```
18:19:07,529,418 receive connect request (SYN) from port 22695 to port 5555 with starting seq 0x0036bfc5 
18:19:07,529,450 send accept (SYN ACK) with starting seq 0x6261d46d
18:19:07,668,343 receive segment containing ClientHello message with seq 0x0036bfc6 len 0x54 
18:19:07,668,359 send ack (through 0x0036c01a) 
18:19:07,668,617 send segment containing ServerHello, Certificate, ServerHelloDone with seq 0x6261d46e len 0x56+0x512+9=0x571 

18:19:08,150,907 after no response ~0.5s, resend segment 

18:19:08,556,603 receive resend of client 0x0036bfc6, which does NOT ack our data;
this implies client didn't get our data-ack and didn't get or accept (either copy of) our 0x6261d46e 
18:19:08,556,617 send probe (ACK with no additional data) 

18:19:08,683,863 receive probe from client, again neg-acking data but pos-acking SYN
18:19:08,683,932 after 2x neg-ack, send FIN (seq 0x6261d9df) 
18:19:08,762,143 receive ACK of our FIN (and data?) (ack=0x6261d9e0)

18:19:16,784,169 receive new connect (SYN) from port 6192 
...
```

This is screwy. If the client is any normal computer with an OS, usually those ack data at TCP level in the protocol stack even if their user program doesn't read (or accept) the data, at least up to some reasonable buffersize. The client is clearly getting at least some of our frames, since it correctly acks SYN and FIN, but **it apparently refuses to ack our data**.

If the client is something like a thermostat or an Arduino, where there is no actual OS but often instead a heap of code someone mashed together, often by copying from websites (including Stack?) without understanding it, so it doesn't work right. Or possibly the actual client is correct, but there is some broken middlebox like a firewall, IDS, 'smart' router, etc. in between.

Anyway if you can't get the TLS protocol messages, which are TCP data, delivered to the client at the TCP level, nothing else can work, so without any more useful info about or control over the client you're out of luck.
Sorry.

Comment: *"...where there is no actual OS but often instead a heap of code someone mashed together..."* - lol.

Comment: the second stream in the capture looks more normal, no retransmission there

Answer (score 0):

> bad gethostbyaddr

A reverse DNS is not working well on your server. With your server IP, run these commands and check if they return anything (I suppose you're on Linux) :

```
dig -x XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Check that your hosts file solves correctly your hostname. If you have to configure a DNS server (/etc/resolv.conf), do it.

Comment: I do not think this is a problem for the SSL handshake (per various comments I found during searches). But yes, I added the device to my DNS, the error message about `gethostbyaddr()` does not appear anymore -- but the rest of the issue is the same.